# Find a Value when a logical condition satisfies R

Tags: r, for-loop, optimization, statistics, time-series

What I am about to explain is kinda tricky, but I hope I can explain it clearly.

1. Suppose you have a function that does the Hodrick Prescott detrending, that is pretty much this:

[image]

The user picks up the λ  value, and therefore for every λ it exists a series trend τ(λ).

2. Suppose you pick a number near 0 (on the positive side)

This number is V, for this case suppose `V=0.0001278846`

3. Then you want to compute this:

[image]

(I have the function that does)

But you want to find a λ so that F(λ) = V

How can I complete this?

I was trying to make a while statement, but could not state it correctly, then I made a `for` loop with an `if` statement to `break` the for loop when `F(λ)-V = 0`.

This is what my for loop looks like:

```
for(L in 1:3500){
    
   F_ <- find_v(dataa, L)
    
    if((F_-V)==0){
      print(paste("The λ value for this series following Rule 1 is:", L))
      break
    }
   cat(paste("The λ =",L,"has a (F-V) difference of:", (F_-V),"\n"))
```

where `dataa` is my data composed of 89 obs.

Using this for loop I see that (F-V) turns negative between L = 3276 and L = 3277.

Is there a better way to do it? Like optimization?

Because using the for loop it feels like I'm obtaining the optimal λ by the force.

---

Sorry for not getting my data or codes for the hodrick prescott detrending or the `find_v` function, they are way too long.

Comment: First your function F is a constant function of lambda. ie there is no lambda on the right hand side of that F equation. So all lambda will give you same value. That F is somewhat incorrect

Comment: That ain't right. F depends on tau, and tau depends on lambda. If lambda changes, all the tau changes, therefore the F value changes.

Comment: How does tau depend on lambda? You have 89 tau's just as you have 89 y's

Comment: Tau depends on lambda because of the minimization. If you solve it analytically, you form a system of equations so that y = tau + lambda F tau. Then you solve for tau, knowing that lambda is a value that the researcher picks.

Comment: This is a "root finding" (or "zero finding") problem. In R, function `uniroot` should help you. (But a grid search, as you did, should be fine as well.) Note that the function for which you want to find the zero (in your case, `g(lambda) = F(lambda) - V` ) can be arbitrarily complex, e.g. it may contain the fitting procedure for the HP-filter.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing double optimization, consider the following:

*The data*

```
set.seed(0)  
y <- rnorm(89)
```

*The function to be optimized:*

```
lfun <- function(tau, y, lambda){
  n <- length(tau)
  tt <- tau[-(1:2)] - 2 * tau[-c(1, n)] + head(tau, -2)
  sum((y-tau)^2) + lambda *sum(tt^2)
}
```

The F function:

```
f_lambda <- function(lambda, y, V = 0){
  tau <- optim(y,lfun,y = y, lambda = lambda, method = 'BFGS')$par
  tt <- tail(tau,-2) - 2 * head(tau[-1], -1) + head(tau, -2)
  sqrt((sum((y-tau)^2)/sum(tt^2) - V)^2)
}
```

Optimizing the F function:

```
optim(0.1, f_lambda, y = y, V=0.0001278846, method="Brent",lower=0, upper=100)

$par
[1] 0.003412824

$value
[1] 2.633131e-10

$counts
function gradient 
      NA       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

Now the `lambda = 0.003412824` gives the desired V ie:

```
f_lambda(0.003412824, y)
[1] 0.0001278843
```

Which is very close to the `V=0.0001278846` you started with.